# Redirect A Page 'Onload' To Open Link In Parent Page

Tags: html, redirect, parent, onload, target

I have a page I need to be redirected to another page 'onload'.

However, I need the link to open in "parent", NOT in the iframe.

The solution below is not working. The link redirects, but still opens in iframe.

I anyone has any helpful advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload=location.href="http://www.somepage.com" target="_parent";>
    </body>
    </html>
```

UPDATE: I solved it this way.....

```
    <body>onload=window.top.location.href="http://www.rebelplanetnews.com";></body>
```